# SQL Nested statement issue with count of products

Tags: mysql

I'm learning about SQL nested statements but I've run into an issue. What I'd like to do is get total sales for books using their book IDs for last month and compare it to sales this month. All purchases are logged in a book_download_log table, table has the following structure

```
Timestamp    Book ID   Price    
May 1st      10        100
May 2nd      20        200
May 3rd      30        300
```

This is my current query

```
SELECT b.book_id, CONCAT(FORMAT(((this_month/last_month)*100)-100,2),'%') AS Diff, this_month, last_month
FROM 
book_download_log b
JOIN
    (SELECT count(*) AS last_month FROM
        book_download_log b
            WHERE b.book_price > 0 AND
            date(b.timestamp) BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-08') t1
 JOIN
    (SELECT count(*) AS this_month FROM
        book_download_log b
            WHERE b.book_price > 0 AND
            date(b.timestamp) BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-08') t2
GROUP BY b.book_id
ORDER BY Diff Desc
```

What I've succeeded in doing is pulling a total count of all books purchased in this period instead of count of individual book purchases. Here's what my result looks like right now

```
Book ID    Diff     This Month     Last Month
1          17.6%    652            577
69         17.6%    652            577
102        17.6%    652            577
```

What do I need to edit to show individual book sales in both periods?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have no idea what this is uspposed to mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with :

```
SELECT
b.book_id as id,
SUM(IF(MONTH(b.timestamp) = MONTH(CURDATE()), b.book_price, 0)) as thisMonth,
SUM(IF(MONTH(b.timestamp) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), b.book_price, 0)) as lastMonth,
CONCAT(SUM(IF(MONTH(b.timestamp) = MONTH(CURDATE()), b.book_price, 0)) - SUM(IF(MONTH(b.timestamp) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), b.book_price, 0)), '%') as diff
FROM book_download_log b
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(b.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-31')
GROUP BY b.book_id
```

This also works accross years ( e.g. you're in january, and last month is then in another year ) and if you have data after current date in database ( e.g. you're in january, and you have data stored in database for february of the same year, it can happen)

See SQL fiddle here to test it :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ec6c8/7

Comment: This is one of the reasons I come to Stack Overflow, learned a few things from this snippet. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you want to group the purchases by month. I chose SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "2017-06-15"). Then get all the purchase of each month with SUM(), not COUNT(). So you should have something like this:

```
Select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "2017-06-15") as Month, Book_id, sum(price) from 
book_download_log group by Book_id, Month
```

Then extract the last month and current month.

```
    SELECT b.book_id, CONCAT(FORMAT(((this_month/last_month)*100)-100,2),'%') 
    AS Diff
    FROM 
    (Select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "2017-06-15") as Month, Book_id, sum(price) from 
     book_download_log group by Book_id, Month)
    join
   Select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "2017-04-15") as Last_Month, Book_id, sum(price) from 
     book_download_log download group by Book_id, Last_Month
    on download.Book_id = book_download_log.Book_id
```

Comment: Note that the question appears to relate to MySQL